# batch file to search in txt file for string and get the full line off the string

Tags: string, line

i want batch file to search in txt file for string and get full line of it

this is the txt file input

1:how are you

3:im fine

2:yeah

```
     for example
     @echo off
     set string=3:
     echo the full line off the string is %fullline%
     pause
```

Comment: did you try  **find "string" file**  on the command line?

Comment: i want find the full line of a string not the string only *_*

Comment: sorry I meant findstr. it shows the complete line.

Comment: if it show the complete line from string ((answer the question with the code))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is a batch file that calls findstr directly, and within a for loop to add text to the line. if you just want the found text delete the line beginning with for.

```
@echo off

set findtext="blah"
set findfile="test.txt"

findstr %findtext% %findfile%

for /f "delims=" %%a in ('findstr %findtext% %findfile%') do echo The full line of the string is %%a
```

[credits](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html)